# NullInjectorError: No provider for PublicClientApplication! MSAL

Tags: angular, typescript, identityserver4, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

I have an Angular application in which I am trying to manage the login using MSAL.
Apparently I'm having a problem and from what I've found online, I'm not providing a provider for PublicClientApplication in my Angular application.
This is the error I get:

```
    ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[PublicClientApplication -> PublicClientApplication -> PublicClientApplication]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for PublicClientApplication!
    at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:7493:27)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:7914:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:7914:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:7914:33)
    at ChainedInjector.get (core.mjs:12084:36)
    at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (core.mjs:3201:39)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.mjs:3246:12)
    at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.mjs:10041:12)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.AppComponent_Factory [as factory] (app.component.ts:12:26)
    at getNodeInjectable (core.mjs:3431:44)
```

**This is the function I have in my app.module**

```
export function MSALInstanceFactory() : IPublicClientApplication {
return new PublicClientApplication({
    auth: {
        clientId: "((my client id))",
        authority:
          "my authority",
        redirectUri: "my redirect uri", 
      },
      system: {
        allowNativeBroker: false,
      }
})
```

}

**And these are the providers I'm using:**

```
                    provide : MSAL_INSTANCE,
                    useFactory : MSALInstanceFactory,
                    },
                    MsalService,
                    MsalGuard,
                    MsalBroadcastService,
```

**I tried to instantiate this function in my app.component**

```
  ngOnInit() {
try {
  MSALInstanceFactory

} catch (error) {
}
```

}

Comment: I think you should inject MsalService. Check the official example: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/msal-lts/samples/msal-angular-v2-samples/angular12-sample-app/src/app/app.component.ts